# Why do strace's timings for -c and -T disagree?

Tags: linux, strace

I have an `rsync` running a no-op (all files are already there) directory copy operation to a network-mounted file system.

Because all files are already there, the only thing that rsync does is `lstat()` syscalls.

If I `strace -c` this, I get this:

```
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    0.076780          30      2524           lstat
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    0.076780                  2524           total

real    0m5.451s
```

But if I `strace -T` (showing time per syscall), I get this:

```
lstat("file1", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=32820,   ...}) = 0 <0.005523>
lstat("file2", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=20816,   ...}) = 0 <0.001529>
lstat("file3", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1828312, ...}) = 0 <0.001991>
lstat("file4", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1823258, ...}) = 0 <0.001326>
lstat("file5", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=32820,   ...}) = 0 <0.006562>
lstat("file6", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=22578,   ...}) = 0 <0.002151>
lstat("file7", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=32835,   ...}) = 0 <0.001705>
lstat("file8", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=25493,   ...}) = 0 <0.001492>
lstat("file9", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1783930, ...}) = 0 <0.001974>
```

**The times are completely off!**

`-c` claims each `lstat` takes roughly `30 usecs/call`, while `-T` shows  about 2 ms/call.

The 2 ms make sense, that's in the order of ping speed for the network mount, but 30 microseconds is just plain impossible.

Why is the value in the `usecs/call` column bogus? Am I misunderstanding it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the strace man page:

> -c          Count  time,  calls,  and  errors for each system call and report a summary on program exit.  **On Linux, this attempts to show
>   system time (CPU time
>                      spent running in the kernel) independent of wall clock time.**  If -c is used with -f or -F (below), only aggregate
>   totals for all  traced  processes
>                      are kept.

(Emphasis added by me.) Most I/O will just make the actual asynchronous call and context switch away, rather than doing some kind of busy loop. `-T` will instead show the wall clock time duration between calling into the kernel, and that call returning.

**Edit:** In later versions, `-w` gives you wait times, rather than system times, so `-c -w` will give you times that should match `-T`.

Comment: Ah, so simple! Thank you. Would you mind, for completeness and the ease of passers-by, to edit your answer to mention the `-c` equivalent to `-T` is `strace -c -w`, which shows the wall time summary instead?

Comment: Done. Note that -w was missing from e.g. the version included in Ubuntu 14.04. Since I mostly use `strace` when I want to troubleshoot in remote environments, I tend to be stuck with older releases (CentOS 6 in some places...).